# OutOfMemory JVM

Tags: java, jvm

estoy haciendo un programa que lee de datos abiertos y almacena en una BD que tengo definida. El programa puede estar hasta 18 horas sin parar la ejecución. El problema que tengo es que después de unas 4 horas de ejecución me sale un error de JVM Heap: OutOfMemory, es decir, la máquina virtual de Java se queda sin memoria y no puede seguir con la ejecución del programa. Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer pruebas a esta parte del programa, pues es la primera vez que me ocurre y no sé cómo abordarlo.

Primeramente, pensé que era un problema de arrays y estructuras de datos que no elimino y reinicio nunca, pero yo pensaba que el recolector de basura de Java se encargaba de esta parte (que no tendría que liberar la memoria manualmente como, por ejemplo, en C), así que, tras revisar mi código, me aseguré que estas estructuras se usaban correctamente.

Pero el problema no ha desaparecido y ahora creo que es por un bucle recursivo que tengo en el código, pero claro, para probarlo necesito ejecutar el programa durante 4 horas y no es nada productivo hacer pruebas así, entonces, ¿hay alguna manera de limitar la memoria para que el error salte en vez de en 4 horas, en menos tiempo de ejecución? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si ejecutar el comando `java -X` veras los parámetros de configuración:

```
java -X
    -Xmixed           ejecución de modo mixto (por defecto)
    -Xint             sólo ejecución de modo interpretado
    -Xbootclasspath:<directorios y archivos zip/jar separados por ;>
                      definir la ruta de acceso de búsqueda para los recursos y clases de inicialización de datos
    -Xbootclasspath/a:<directorios y archivos zip/jar separados por ;>
                      agregar al final de la ruta de acceso de la clase de inicialización de datos
    -Xbootclasspath/p:<directorios y archivos zip/jar separados por ;>
                      anteponer a la ruta de acceso de la clase de inicialización de datos
    -Xdiag            mostrar mensajes de diagnóstico adicionales
    -Xnoclassgc       desactivar la recolección de basura de clases
    -Xincgc           activar la recolección de basura de clases
    -Xloggc:<archivo> registrar el estado de GC en un archivo con registros de hora
    -Xbatch           desactivar compilación en segundo plano
    -Xms<tamaño>      definir tamaño de pila Java inicial
    -Xmx<tamaño>      definir tamaño de pila Java máximo
    -Xss<tamaño>      definir tamaño de la pila del thread de Java
    -Xprof            datos de salida de creación de perfil de CPU
    -Xfuture          activar las comprobaciones más estrictas, anticipándose al futuro valor por defecto
```

Aquí te puedes enfocar en `-Xmx` que limita el máximo de memoria que puede utilizar la JVM, lo pasas como parámetro de ejecución si quieres la cantidad en Megabytes `-Xmx128m` y si es en Gigabyte `-Xmx1G`, otro enfoque puedes utilizar `java flight recorder` para ver el funcionamiento de tu programa y detectar que es lo que llena la memoria, si bien el GC elimina la memoria no utilizada hay casos donde la referencia a los objetos no son eliminadas por problemas de programación en tu código, al no poder ver el Código es imposible depurar estos casos, también habría que analizar el bucle infinito y si es necesario poner algun limitador o cambiar el enfoque del problema para prescindir del bucle.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. El codigo es demasiado extenso como para ponerlo aquí, por eso he preferido no hacerlo. No hay bucles infinitos, lo que se hace es como una lectura de una lista enlazada usando recursion que hasta que no llega al ultimo nodo no vuelve hacia atras, y creo que ahi puede estar el problema.

Comment: Si no es un árbol o un grafo, deberías poder transformar ese método recursivo en una iteración sin demasiado esfuerzo

Comment: @lRetro, cuidado con la recursión: yo apostaría a que nunca llega a salir en alguna de las condiciones y es lo que te está provocando el problema.

Comment: @RaulLuna si sale, lo tengo confirmado, pero hace una recursión demasiado extensa. He optado por cambiar la recursión por un bucle while, así cuando acabe una vuelta del while se (deberia) eliminará la memoria utilizada en esa iteración